# Bad performace of virtualized Fedora 20

Tags: virtualhost, fedora, vmware-vsphere

I have a problem with bad performance of Fedora 20 OS running on host which is shared by multiple virtual machines. All actions like typing, opening menu, etc. have 3 seconds or longer delay. It looks like the OS has not enough memory, but I can see no difference with RAM size set in range 512MB - 4GB. I have the VMware tools installed. The other virtual machines are running smoothly (1x Win7, 2x Ubuntu) and there is a plenty of free RAM left on the host (5GB+). The Fedora VM was running fine back on my PC before I converted it to vSphere client. I did the same procedure with Debian 7 which was running smoothly before it had to be replaced with Fedora 20, so I guess the issue is with Fedora OS itself. I have tried to increasing video memory and changing Gnome3 to Gnome classic and KDE but with a little success. Where can be the problem?

Comment: Does the VM have hardware virtualization enabled?

Comment: You're using the GUI on an ESXi-based virtual machine? How does the system perform from the command line?

Comment: @Halfgaar: yes, it has HWV enabled;
ewwhite: the system performs without a problem from the command line
i just noticed that with KDE, when I'm for example using terminal or File manager there is no delay as long as I don't move with windows

Comment: Perhaps you need to turn off desktop effects. Or enable video hardware acceleration, if that works OK (never tried it).

Comment: @Halfgaar Just turning off the desktop effects did it for me, thanks! Well, that was a really dumb question from me... should I delete it or leave it here?

Comment: @Halfgaar - You should write that down as an answer. 0x0000eWan - you shouldn't delete the question. Once there's an answer you should accept it. If, for any reason, Halfgaar doesn't feel like writing the answer, please write it down with full attribution and accept later.

Comment: Good old llvmpipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I already know this was the answer :) I initially didn't write it as an answer because it was a guess.)

Perhaps you need to turn off desktop effects. Or enable video hardware acceleration, if that works OK (never tried it).